# How to plot two lines on the same interactive graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh, panel, holoviews

is it possible to plot two lines on the same graph? I am using Panel on Jupyter. However, I only can plot two lines on two different graphs. I would like to have everything on the same graph to compare results while I am changing input values.

I do not care if I have to use Panel, Bokeh, Holoview, etc.

Best regards,
VQ

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension()
import panel.widgets as pnw
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mplplot(df, **kwargs):
    fig = df.plot(title='Title - Convert temperature from degree Celsius to Kelvin') 


    fig.legend(["Temperature"]);
    fig.set_xlabel("Celcius")
    fig.set_ylabel("Kelvin")
    fig= fig.get_figure()
    plt.close(fig)
    return fig


def Celsius_to_Kelvin(C=100, view_fn=mplplot):
    C = np.arange(0,C, 1)    
    K = (C + 273.15)
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(y=K), index=C)

    return view_fn(df, K=K, C=C)

def Celsius_to_Kelvin1(C=100, view_fn=mplplot):
    C = np.arange(0,C, 1)    
    K = (C + 273.15)
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(y=K), index=C)

    return view_fn(df, K=K, C=C)


C  = pnw.FloatSlider(name='C', value=50, start=0, end=100) 
C1  = pnw.FloatSlider(name='C1', value=40, start=0, end=100)

@pn.depends(C.param.value)
def Celsius_to_Kelvin_variables(C):
    return Celsius_to_Kelvin(C)

@pn.depends(C1.param.value)
def Celsius_to_Kelvin_variables1(C1):
    return Celsius_to_Kelvin1(C1)

widgets    = pn.Column("<br>\n#### Variable configuration", C, C1)
Celsius_to_Kelvin_panel = pn.Row(Celsius_to_Kelvin_variables, Celsius_to_Kelvin_variables1, widgets)

Celsius_to_Kelvin_panel
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can plot two lines on the same graph using just about any plotting library. To do it, you follow the instructions for whatever plotting library you are using; Panel will be able to plot whatever you come up with (but is otherwise not involved in such overlays). Here your code is using Pandas .plot(), which as far as I know only makes overlaid plots for data in the same dataframe, but you can use the native Matplotlib API to create the plot directly. See e.g. https://python-graph-gallery.com/122-multiple-lines-chart/ or the Matplotlib documentation.